# Condição IF - Exibir ou Ocultar TextBox

Tags: vba, excel-vba, microsoft-excel

Caros,

Tenho 4 optionButton (2 grupos diferentes), onde 2 representam "Sim" e "Não" para duas perguntas diferentes.

O que quero fazer:

Quando o usuário escolher a opção NÃO no grupo1 e depois escolher a opção SIM no grupo2 sejá exibido um textobox para explicar o motivo das respostas não serem iguais (já consigo fazer isso).

E quando ele alterar a opção do grupo1 para SIM, no grupo2 tem que ocultar o campo do textbox.

Detalhe: Os optionButtons ficam em multiabas diferentes*

Problema:

Quando o usuário está trocando a opção do grupo1 para SIM, não está ocultando a textbox do grupo2.

Código até o momento:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
If simSIMONI.Value = naoSISUP.Value Then
    motNaoSIMONI.Visible = True
    labMotNaoSIMONI.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Você colocou visible como true... não irá ocultar mesmo coloque false

Comment: Você precisa usar os eventos dos próprios botões de opção. No seu código está usando o clique no formulário, o que não faz sentido.

Comment: @AndersonHenrique, essa é um exemplo só. foi um mau exemplo de código

Comment: @PedroMVM eu queria não ter que colocar em todos, pois são muitos. Por isso tentei colocar direto no Form.

Comment: Se realmente há muitos Eventos de Change, você pode criar um módulo de classe de evento Change em option buttons dentro deste Userform. É um pouco mais complexo, porém quando uma janela iterativa de usuário é criada com muitos botões, isto pode facilitar a programação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caros,

Resolvido. Tentei não ter que colocar validação em cada optionbutton, mas não consegui.

Coloquei a validação em alguns optionButtons com if.

**Exemplo** do código

```
Private Sub simSISUP_Change()
If simSIMONI.Value = True And simSISUP.Value = True Then
    motNaoSIMONI.Visible = False
    labMotNaoSIMONI.Visible = False
End If
End Sub


Private Sub simSIMONI_Change()
If simSIMONI.Value = True And naoSISUP.Value = True Then
        motNaoSIMONI.Visible = True
        labMotNaoSIMONI.Visible = True
    Else:
        motNaoSIMONI.Visible = False
        labMotNaoSIMONI.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```